The scanf function uses '%c' to accept input, but can perform string input
How to understand the running process of the following code.
void scan(void){
    char item;
    scanf("%c",&item);
    if(item == '#'){
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("%c",item);
    scan();
}

Why can I input strings into the console, and scanf will not be executed again in the recursion, but each character will be read automatically instead?

You call scanf multiple times, each one reads a single character. The input and buffering of the line is done in the terminal not your program.

Because the input if buffered. The %c reads one character and the rest remain in the buffer. You should find that scanf() is executed in the recursion, and %c does not read a string.

A side note: why do you use recursion here ? A simple loop can be implemented to result in the same behavior.

By the way, if there's an error reading the input (and that includes EOF) you will enter infinite recursion. You should always check what scanf returns.

Conversely, if you have scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) and you type 1<Enter>2<Enter>3<Enter> the scanf() will wait until the third Enter to complete.

Generally getchar() and putchar() are better choices if all you have in your format string is "%c". Also, what happens in your code if text is piped to your program without a '\n' or the user presses ctrl + d (or ctrl + z on windows) to generate a manual EOF to end input?

@Mingyu Su,  Detail: "Why can I input strings into the console ..." You are not entering C strings, (a sequence of characters up to and including a null character).  Instead you are entering in the console a line (a sequence of characters up to and including a line feed).  This code, by reading, is not forming a C string.

@Someprogrammerdude, the buffering is done in stdio library, not at the terminal.  The terminal buffers only one line of data, but if he reads from a file, a full buffer is filled before the scanf() returns.

scanf() is a routine part of stdio library, which buffers input and output.
In your case, I assume you are reading from a terminal, so a full line is normally read in a single read() call (scanf() calls read() with a full buffer space to allow avoiding to make a system call for every character you read)
This means the following scan() calls will take the character from the still unread characters in the buffer, until it consumes them all.  Then, it will call read() again to try to fill the buffer.
Note:  Calling recursively to scan() will enter deeply into itself, and remembering the place to return back will fill the stack if your file is big enough (try your program with a big file with no # characters, and you will see your program crashing because of a StackOverflow --smile on the pun :) )
Note2:  If you are trying to do this to print the characters in reverse order, you must put the printf() after the recursive call.
